# Ubuntu + Vmware

Tags: server, vmware, remote-desktop

I already asked this question on vmware forums but no proper answer.

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Dedicated Server (hosting company).
Server specs:
--> Intel Xeon E5-1650V3: 6 Cores, 12 Hyperthreading
--> 128 GB Ram
--> 512 GB SSD

Iam using Vmware Workstation Pro 16.2 (the newest)

I have 6 Win10 VM's. Each VM has 2 vCpu allocated, which works fine.
I connect to Vms via RDP.
The problem is: the Server freezes randomly. For eg. the server was running for about 3 weeks and then suddenly the VM's became unconnectable via RDP.
When I connect to the server via RDP (xrdp) it becomes unresponsive (similar to windows not responding).
Then I have to hardware reset the Server from hosting panel and start the VM's again and this repeats every 2-3 weeks.

I cant really find anything at logs (Iam not a linux expert).
I made this test-> I stressed the 6 Win10 VM's with Heavyload and monitored it via htop, the Cpu cores go to 100% but the server doesnt freeze. I assume its not a hardware problem.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Without a specific error, it's hard to give good advice. Also, I don't imagine there are many people who use VMWare Workstation on Ubuntu because the built in tools are amazing, and usually the most performant. However, here is some general advice to get you started:

- The system log is located in `/var/log/syslog`. You can search for error messages in it with `grep -Ei err\|fail\|stop\|denied /var/log/syslog`
- Also check systemd logs for errors with `journalctl | grep -Ei err\|fail\|stop\|denied`
- apply all updates - there could be a known bug in a piece of software you are using. `apt update ; apt dist-upgrade`
- sometimes a system will become unresponsive due to excessive swap use, you can check with `free -m`, temporarily disable with `swapoff -a`, or significantly reduce swap usage with `sysctl vm.swappiness=1`

Hopefully there is something here that will help you find a specific problem, for which you may ask a new question.